# How to add a smooth replacement to a div inside a gird container?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, css-grid

## `FIRST Run the script below to understand what I'm talking about here`

### What we have here

Well, we have a box and a container.

After 2 seconds it starts moving from the position 1 to the position 2.

The js code basically changes the `grid-column` property of the box to replace it.

### Problem

How can I make its movement a bit smoother?
Like, `transition: all 1s` does not work. Any ideas?

```js
setTimeout( () => {
    const box = document.getElementById("box");
    

    box.classList.remove("pos-1");
    
    box.classList.add("pos-2");
    
  
}, 2000);
```

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  
  display: grid;
  
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
}

#box {
  background-color: red
}


.pos-1 {
  grid-column: 1;
  
}

.pos-2 {
  grid-column: 4;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="pos-1" id="box"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use a span with transition move effect, then when it arrives at the desired position, set it's display to none; and set box display at the new place in the grid =)

Comment: It will not be smooth the way you setting it up. There is no transition coordinates wise as you not letting it move from one position to another. You let it jump from one cell into another where it skips all space inbetween.

Comment: You can't apply transitions to `grid-column` property (column position), only `grid-template-columns` property (column size).

Comment: well i think html { scroll-behavior: smooth;} on html tag should be ease this

Comment: @NishantShamVispute how so? `scroll-behavior: smooth;` will not ensure a smooth transition. It has nothing to do with the issue at hand. Is only changes the jump behavior from jump to scroll if you use an `anchor` targeting from a `hyper reference`. There is no anchor, no hyper referneces or targets involved here.

Comment: You could do this with a css animation and embelish with a setTimeout. You will have to use position on an absolute positioned element though. But if you set it up right you could move it the distance your grid is going to be....

Comment: or you could use math in this case so you can divide the screen size on the grid columns, then multiple it by 4 to get the 4th column place into the animation ?!

Comment: your are right @tacoshy there is no navigational scroll happing here.. i gues then `keyframes` is the only way to go in this case

Answer (score 0):

No way I know to do this using grid elements like you want, however you can use a CSS animation and get a nice tween animation using @keyframes. Then use a setTimeout to set your element where it is at the end of the keyframe using JS. I also use the root element to send variables so everything is on the same duration. A conditional splits a two second timeout `2000` to `2s` and sends that over to the root element for use in the CSS animation duration.

```js
const root = document.documentElement; //--> <html> element
const box = document.getElementById("box");
const distance = `150px`;
const duration = 2000;

const move = (distance, duration) => {
  // the conditional makes sure the setTimeout time and duration time in the css are the same
  // transform the duration into proper seconds for the CSS animations on the CSS side
  if (`${duration}`.length > 3) {
    let whole = `${duration}`.slice(0, `${duration}`.length - 3);
    root.style.setProperty('--duration', `${whole}s`);
  } else { // this is  milliseconds send over as is
    root.style.setProperty('--duration', `.${duration}s`);
  }
  // send the distance over to the root element (HTML) and 
  // transfer to target element using a css variable in css
  root.style.setProperty('--distance', distance);

  // timeout to set the elements position at the end of the keyframe tween
  setTimeout(() => {
    box.style.transform = `translateX(${distance})`;
  }, duration + 10);
}

 move(distance, duration);
```

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
  position: relative;
}

#box {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  animation: moveToRight var(--duration) ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes moveToRight {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(var(--distance));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span id="box"></span>
</div>
```